# Android - Socket.io clients in room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Hi all :)**

I need to get all clients in a room.

I have found the following code and it's works:

```
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['queue'].sockets;
// Output is client ID and true/false value
```

The issue is that I need the socket ID from each client.

```
clients.id or clients.socket.id ..
```

Does not work. Output is undifined.

Has anyone a solution for my issue ?

**Second question:**
Alternativ was my idea that I put all user ID's if the client is joining in a javascript array or list etc. But if I have above 500 or 1000 clients in a list .. I think that is a little bit unfavorable ?

Thanks
David